# Flash Component Definition Constructor Not Running

Tags: flash, components

I am trying to run a constructor of a Flash component.

The constructor looks like this.

```
    public function Proceed() 
    {
        super();
        this.displayText.text = 'hi';
        trace("Proceed button constructor.");

    }
```

Only, nothing appears to load.

Comment: Rationale for downvote? Has downvoter ever made a Flash Component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, that in addition to having a component definition defining your class, the flash symbol also needs to subclass that class and have "export for actionscript."